# JTable error Column Count Doesnot Match ValueCount at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have a Jtable with six columns. I am displaying the contents of my database into my Jtable. Its working fine.

But I am facing trouble updating the changes done in Jtable cells to appropriate database cell.

In the below code when I tried to edit the First Row ,third column in my Jtable, it does not get reflected in the First row, third column in my database, Indeed im getting an error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1".

Here is my code which I created the JTable using defaultTable Model.

```
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

if(e.getType()==TableModelEvent.UPDATE){

    Object value =  dm.getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(), e.getColumn());
    System.out.print(value);

    try {
        statement =(Statement) dbConnection.createStatement();

int count = statement.executeUpdate ("INSERT INTO incident(,field2) VALUES ('"+value+"')");



    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Don't know if it's a type or not, but it looks wrong to me - `incident(,field2)`

Comment: Im sorry, typo error. This is the correct statement which gives error int count = statement.executeUpdate ("INSERT INTO incident VALUES ('"+value+"')");

Comment: override setValueAt invoked a new instanceof SwingWorker / Runnable#THread for DefaultTableModel instead of firing hard, unsafe and long running JDBC from TableModelListener

Comment: could you please give me some sample code or further explanation on how to do that....  is my code logically wrong in getting the values and updating in database ?

Comment: [crossposted on Daniweb](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/462075/column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1)

Comment: is my code logically wrong in getting the values and updating in database ? == not, but is against natural rulles to store anything to Database on fly (I know this is basic property for high accesible and profesional application), start with saving changes from JButtons ActionListener, btw you miss there logics for storing whatever without coordinates, logical ordering etc, or any change in JTable is stored to database without any logics

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that has no typos; also include the schema and full error message/stack-trace.